# Upgrade ReactiveMongo Play 2.3 app from 2.6 to 3.0

Tags: scala, heroku, playframework, mlab, play-reactivemongo

I had a perfectly good working Scala Play 2.3 app using ReactiveMongo running on Heroku against a MongoLab 2.6 database, now that MongoLab have updated their sandbox databases to 3.0 I can not get my app to start up.

I have updated my local database to 3.0.

I have followed the instructions on http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/documentation/tutorial/play2.html for 2.3, but I still get a stacktrace as follows:

> --- (Running the application from SBT, auto-reloading is enabled) ---
>
> [info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000
>
> (Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)
>
> [info] application - ReactiveMongoPlugin starting... [info]
>   application - ReactiveMongoPlugin successfully started with db
>   'sites'! Servers:
>                   [localhost:27017] [info] play - Application started (Dev) [ERROR] [10/02/2015 11:34:11.472]
>   [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] [ActorSystem(play)] Uncaught
>   error from thread [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] shutting down
>   JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled
>   java.lang.AbstractMethodError
>           at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
>           at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
>           at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
>           at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
>           at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
>           at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
>           at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
>           at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
>           at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
>
> [ERROR] [10/02/2015 11:34:11.473]
>   [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] [ActorSystem(play)] Uncaught
>   error from thread [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] shutting down
>   JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled
>   java.lang.AbstractMethodError Uncaught error from thread
>   [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] shutting down JVM since
>   'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[play]
>   java.lang.AbstractMethodError
>           at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
>           at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
>           at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
>           at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
>           at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
>           at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
>           at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:580)
>           at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
>           at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
>           at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
>           at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:456)
>           at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:478)

I've updated my references from ...default.BSONCollection to ...bson.BSONCollection etc.

I'm using the following config:

```
mongodb.uri = "mongodb://localhost:27017/sites" 

mongo-async-driver {   

  akka {

    loglevel = WARNING   

  } 

}
```

My app dependency is:

```
"org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.11.7.play23")
```

Please can someone advise on what the above stacktrace actually means as I can't figure that out?

Comment: Experiencing similar issue, cannot get my play app to authenticate against mongolab. Keep getting authorization errors.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure whats going on in your stacktrace but it looks like that setting `akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error` is just causing your app to crash rather than output what is causing the crash

Reading through the docs you might be able to disable it by doing something like this:

```
jvm-exit-on-fatal-error = off
```

In your akka config. Then you might get some more detailed stacktrace

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/configuration.html

However I was also getting a fatal error after the Mongo 3.0 upgrade on MongoLab. My Error was this:

```
DatabaseException['not authorized for query on auth-test.user' (code = 13)]
```

Caused by 3.0 using a different authentication then 2.6

> mongo 2.6 uses MONGODB-CR auth protocol and 3.0 uses MONGODB-SHA-1 by
>   default

To solve I changed my MongoURI to include authMode like this:

```
mongodb.uri = "mongodb://user:password@ds049621.mongolab.com:49431/DBName?authMode=scram-sha1"
```